# Empty uri is not allowed

Tags: graphdb, data-import

The error below is prompted when I attempt to load [dataset](https://lds-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/lcnaf.both.nt.zip) into GraphDB using Preload tool. Does it mean that GraphDB does not allow empty URI? Can this error be skipped and the data loading can be continued?

```
org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.RDFParseException: Empty uri is not allowed [line 460940,column 1] in lcnaf.both.nt [line 460940, column 1]
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.util.RDFLoader.loadZip(RDFLoader.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.util.RDFLoader.load(RDFLoader.java:193)
        at com.ontotext.load.GraphdbRDFLoader.load(GraphdbRDFLoader.java:98)
        at com.ontotext.graphdb.loadrdf.PreloadData.processSingleFileInternal(PreloadData.java:1389)
        at com.ontotext.graphdb.loadrdf.PreloadData.lambda$processSingleFile$16(PreloadData.java:1325)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.ontotext.rio.ntriples.NQuadsSimpleParser$NodeParsingException: Empty uri is not allowed [line 460940, column 1]
        at com.ontotext.rio.ntriples.NQuadsSimpleParser.findUriEndPos(NQuadsSimpleParser.java:346)
        at com.ontotext.rio.ntriples.NQuadsSimpleParser.scan(NQuadsSimpleParser.java:385)
        at com.ontotext.rio.ntriples.NQuadsSimpleParser.parse(NQuadsSimpleParser.java:229)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.util.RDFLoader.loadInputStreamOrReader(RDFLoader.java:288)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.util.RDFLoader.load(RDFLoader.java:228)
        at com.ontotext.load.GraphdbRDFLoader.load(GraphdbRDFLoader.java:91)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.util.RDFLoader.loadZip(RDFLoader.java:245)
        ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a property when starting GraphDB to skip the invalid values - graphdb.engine.entity.validate=false

More on that in the documentation - https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/configuring-graphdb.html#engine-properties